# How to run a shell script at startup for Red Hat 7.3

Tags: linux, shell, startup

I want to run a script when my RHEL 7.3 machine boots up. The script restarts docker service and restarts my container.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service docker start
sleep 10s
docker restart Free
```

How do I get this script to run every time my Red Hat machine is powered on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, did you try googling before asking here? There are plenty of pages that explain you how to do it

Comment: This solution worked for me with `chkconfig` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way to add you script into the file `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Didn't work for me, but the variant of Rhel I'm using is heavily modified by an uncooperative IT team